# Zero Gauss curvature surfaces spanning a loop

Tags: differential-geometry

EDIT 1:

Spanning across a given arbitrary closed boundary/loop a surface can be defined with zero mean curvature H in 3-space as minimal surfaces.

Likewise can a surface be defined with zero Gauss curvature K? We need to integrate r t = s^2 with a prescribed boundary.

Comment: no. Just take the laces on a baseball. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developable_surface  ...and... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseball_%28ball%29 ...and... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monge%E2%80%93Amp%C3%A8re_equation